# Can't see any startup choices when I start-up the laptop

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, boot-failure

I try to install Ubuntu 12.04 in different partition. After completion of my Ubuntu installation. My laptop restart but I can't see any boot loader or start up choose what OS I want to choose(windows or Ubuntu) . After this I can't run my window 7 also, One blink _ sign appears on my blank black screen. So what can I do for run windows or Ubuntu.

After this again I try to install complete Ubuntu via USB flash disk. but I have 400gb hard disk, in one drive `/dev/sda4/` but have 3 partition in window after Ubuntu installation c d e.

How to recover my windows7.

Comment: I guess you installed the bootloader in USB drive , try booting when USB drive is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Hold <kbd>F8</kbd> when the computer boots and the boot loader prompt should appear.

Comment: i haven't see any thing when laptop restart and hold F8. it doesnot work. only i see "-" sign in black screen.

Answer (score 0):

see if this helps, start with your USB key, but instead of installing go to the graphical environmnent and run the terminal, then you need to:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/XXX
```

The above command install the boot manager in your disk (XXX), if you don't know the name of the device, you can run the following in the terminal

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

After this, restart and boot into both Ubuntu or Windows.

I took this from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) , see if it helps you
Cheers